# Why is Jenkins having problems with UTF 8

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job running. I just want to get all files. In every file name there is a Chinese letter. So the problem is now that Jenkins has problems reading in those files. Jenkins makes just "?" out of the Asian letter. The second problem is. Actually it is more than 100 files. But Jenkins only gives me 20 files. Maybe now a lot of files will look the same because of the question mark "?" .

Does anyone know how I can fix this. The problem only occurs on Jenkins ( running on Linux ) . On my local machine in Eclipse it works though.

```
    File resourcePath = new File("resources/china_data/");
    File[] files = resourcePath.listFiles();

    for (final File file : files)
    {
        System.out.console(file.getName);
    }
```

Comment: Is `System.out.console` a thing?

Comment: What ? Of course it just prints to console. In Eclipse and also in Jenkins

Comment: It does not work in Java 1.8.0_181 for me, and I can't find it in the [javadoc for PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html). Normally you would print to console with `System.out.println`, while `System.out.console` would result in a `error: cannot find symbol`. Is it possible that you're editing the wrong file?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to use the new java.nio.Path api in place of the java.io.File api

Also try setting the below in your code initially.

```
System.setProperty("sun.jnu.encoding","utf-8");
System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried this already. But still it did not recognise Asian/ Chinese letters . But only the problem occured in Jenkins !!

Comment: @Julia19 I have updated answer. Could you try that also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `System.out.println`, this happens when the program runs with an ASCII locale:

```
$ cat Main.java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File resourcePath = new File("resources/china_data/");
    File[] files = resourcePath.listFiles();
    for (final File file : files)
    {
      System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
  }
}

$ javac Main.java
$ LC_CTYPE=C java Main
???????
```

When the program runs with a UTF-8 capable locale, either from the environment or configured through Java, you get the expected result:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 java Main
中华人民共和国

$ LC_CTYPE=C java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Main
中华人民共和国
```

If you're not sure how to configure your server, you can also do this from within Java:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8")); maybe that would solve the issue of printing to console, but not if I assign it to a string . E.g. String filename = file.getFileName();

Comment: The problem in your code is writing the filename, not reading it.